# Altium Schematic - save all sheets as ASCII schdoc

Tags: altium, design, ascii

I see a way to save as in Altium to save the sheet in ascii format. Will this save all sheets in a hierarchical design or flat design?

https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/sch-dlg-schconfirmfileformatformfile-format-sch-ad

There are 60 sheets in the design so does each sheet have to be saved as ascii SCHDOC?  and if so, will it be saved off seperately so the designer can continue using his binary versions of Schdoc?

I am a very limited Altium user without personal access to the software, but trying to direct the designer using Altium on how to export.

Comment: What is the purpose of exporting to ASCII? Many schematic programs can export/import native formats.

Comment: Try it with an example project

Comment: please note the question included "without personal access to the software", hence "try it" is not useful.  I'm trying to direct a designer on how to export.

Comment: its understood the wide variety of netlisters available as well as save as to Orcad, PCad etc.   The question is asked with this in mind.  Altium provides a choice of saving schdoc to binary or ascii file.  So I am not alone in understanding the benefits of the ascii file.   Simply put we need to do post processing on the data in the schematic and there is a wealth of information in the design which can be used elsewhere.

Comment: Although I tend to like Altium questions and answers on this site over the official forum, I think this question is better suited to Altium support.

Comment: yes thanks.  that's useful for registered users, see original post.